# What is the best way to manage a class with lots of properties?

Tags: architecture, coding-style, code-quality, clean-code

We have one table `meta` where there is `key and value` so each of the row represents one component or service and then we have api system which manages the `metas database`. And it was going pretty well when we had `10 rows = 10` properties now it grew to be 30 and its so annoying i am using php and lets say it looks like

```
Class metas {
private $metas1=[]
private $metas2=[]
private $metas3=[]
}
```

Now i think the best way to manage this class is to put these keys on yml file but is it the best way?

Comment: You have implemented something known as [EAV](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity–attribute–value_model). Take a look at the link because Wikipedia also introduce alternatives, like turning this model into mere jsons (some SQL DB supports specific types for json)

Comment: Using a proper config file (like YML, or TOML, or even .ini) seems reasonable. This is clearly data, it should not mix with code proper.

Comment: What is annoying?

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you start numbering your properties, such as:

```
private int myField1;
private int myField2;
private int myField3;
```

What you're really doing here is trying to hardcode a list, and you should be using a collection type instead (whether an array, list, or any other collection type is contextual and language dependent):

```
private int[] myFields;
```

This example uses `int` as the base type, but that is not the case for you.

I suspect this is PHP (due to the `$`)? Your example is a bit light on the specific ypes being used, and I'm no PHP dev, but it seems to me that your individual fields are already some sort of collection type (due to the `[]`), so the type of your "list of fields" property will be something along the line of an array of arrays, also known as a [multi-dimensional array](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_arrays_multidimensional.asp)

The example code on the page I linked seems to match your goal of a key/value dictionary:

```
$cars = array (
  array("Volvo",22,18),
  array("BMW",15,13),
  array("Saab",5,2),
  array("Land Rover",17,15)
);
```